# Why Does This Code Freeze When N>=10?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a program written in C++11.

When text.in has a value of N<10 this program works fine. However, when N is increased to say 11, it freezes and seems to go on forever. Why could this be?

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int dp[40][391]={0};

int main() {
    FILE* in = fopen("text.in","r");
    FILE* out = fopen("text.out","w");
    int N; 
    fscanf(in,"%d",&N); 
    int sum = N*(N+1)/2;
    for (int i=0; i<=N; i++) dp[0][i]=1;
    if (sum%2==1) {fprintf(out,"0"); return 0;}
    for (int n=1; n<=sum; n++) {
        for (int k=1; k<=N; k++) {
            if (n-k>=0) dp[n][k]=dp[n-k][k-1];
            dp[n][k]+=dp[n][k-1];
        }
    }
    fprintf(out,"%d",dp[sum/2][N]/2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that works with `N == 9`.

You define

```
int dp[40][391]
```

and you read/write in it

```
if (n-k>=0) dp[n][k]=dp[n-k][k-1];
   dp[n][k]+=dp[n][k-1];
```

with a first index `n` with range from `1` to `sum` where

```
int sum = N*(N+1)/2;
```

So if `N < 9`, `sum` is lower that `40`; if `N>=9`, `sum` is greater than `40` [`sum == 45` for `N == 9`; `sum == 55` for `N == 10`; `sum = 66` for `N == 11`.

So, with `N == 11` you write `dp[66][k]` when the top legal value for the first index is `39`.

Wonderful recipe for a disaster.